# not able to save data into plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I used one old example to save data into a plist.Data coming from plist is working fine but it's not changing or editing when I am trying to save data into a plist.even I am not getting any error massages.My code to save data is -

```
 -(void)saveData
 {
   // get paths from root direcory
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   // get documents path
   NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   // get the path to our Data/plist file
   NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

  // set the variables to the values in the text fields
  personName = self.nameEntered.text;
  phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
  [phoneNumbers addObject:self.homePhone.text];
  [phoneNumbers addObject:self.workPhone.text];
  [phoneNumbers addObject:self.cellPhone.text];

  // create dictionary with values in UITextFields
  NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personName, phoneNumbers, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Phones", nil]];

  NSString *error = nil;
  // create NSData from dictionary
  NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

  // check is plistData exists
  if(plistData)
  {
    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just go from dictionary to file. It will save it out as a plist.

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personName, phoneNumbers, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Phones", nil]];

NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@", plistDict);    
NSLog(@"Saving to %@", plistPath);

[plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

I am assuming your plistPath is legit.

Comment: You need to be more specific. How do you know it is not working? Are you running this on the sim or device. I added some NSLogs in the code. Add that and tell me what the output is. BTW, your statement of " but it's not changing or editing when I am trying to save data into a plist" is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I tested it on simulator and device too..I checked the plist file when I clicked on save button.There is no changes happen in plist file.

Comment: If you want help, you need to supply more info. I actually asked for some items above. And an additional q is how do you know the plist file has not changed?

Comment: "http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?tag=ios-saving-data-to-plist-tutorial" I am using this demo for plist.I am checking my created Data.plist file and even after clicking on "Save" button it's not updating my view and plist file too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally good. I tried the same code in my machine its working fine. If still you are facing the same issue then you can use below api and check for creating `NSData` from `dictionary`

> +(NSData *)dataWithPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format
>   options:(NSPropertyListWriteOptions)opt error:(out NSError **)error